# How to send multiple emails from database as CC with PHPMailer?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I have a database. The fields are `id`, `email` and `city`. I want to send some email to all emails in my database.

In e.g case: I live in a city, so I want to send an email to all emails matchting my city.

I have wrote my method code like this:

```
 $kota = mysql_real_escape_string(stripcslashes( $_POST['kota']));
        $baca_kota = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM conselor WHERE kota='$kota'");
        while($read = mysql_fetch_array($baca_kota))

        {

            $emailcc = $read['email'];
        }

        require '../phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
        require '../phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php';

        $mail = new PHPMailer;
        //$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

        $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
            $mail->Host = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
            $mail->Username = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';                 // SMTP username
            $mail->Password = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';                           // SMTP password
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
            $mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to

        $mail->setFrom($email,$name);
        $mail->addAddress('stevanlai04@gmail.com');     // Add a recipient
        $mail->addReplyTo($email);
        $mail->addCC($emailcc);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do `$mail->addCC($emailcc);` inside the loop:

```
while ($read = mysql_fetch_array($baca_kota)) {
    $emailcc = $read['email'];
    $mail->addCC($emailcc);
}
```

Comment: ohhh yahh oh my God.. it's a simple logic.. thankyou very much it's work

Comment: Yep :) sometimes it happens even to the best of us

Answer (score 0):

all you need to call Send() method from your PHPmailer sdk in your

```
while  

     $this->mail->IsSMTP(); 
     $this->mail->SMTPAuth = true;
     $this->mail->Host = 'mail.example.com';
    //$this->mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';   
     $this->mail->Port =25;

     $this->mail->Username = 'mail@example.com';
     $this->mail->Password = 'your password';

    foreach($listemails as $key=>val){
     $this->mail->SetFrom($val["email address"], 'topic');
$this->mail->Send();
    }
```

Edit: Also you can create a function that function send email and it returns itself! for example

```
 function sendemail($emailaddres){

    // call your phpmailler medhot
    / and return it
$this->mail->Send()
    return sendemail($val["email address"])
```

Comment: This code will result in too many messages being sent; if you set 5 recipients it will send 15 messages. You need to call send at a later point, as the other answer does.

Comment: yes you right sometimes server can make problem for PHPmailler recipients so I try to do it with another way